# Property file configuration after build, before deployment

Tags: spring, tomcat, properties, properties-file

Certain properties have been included in the properties file, referenced by the Spring's ApplicationConfiguration file (java based configuration). These are mostly url's and database properties which would vary based on the deployment environment.

The plan is to place the property file in the classpath. How would I be able to change the property file after the builld(Jenkins) is taken. I should be able to change the property file and deploy it again in the respective environment, without taking a new build. Any suggestions please?

Comment: Place the properties file in the conf directory of your tomcat. That path should be in the classpath of it

Comment: Are you looking for something more sophisticated than replacing the file inside jar/war manually (it's a ZIP file, so any archiever will do). If so, what are your requirements?

Comment: @JiriTousek No. So I just need to take the war file, unzip it, edit the properties file and then zip it again? But I guess having it as part of tomcat properties would be more convenient, so that the deployment team can handle this based on the environments?

Comment: @Jens Did the same. Could you please check my comments for the below answer?

Comment: @Chillax Plaese verify if the conf directory is in classptah

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Spring documentation provides plenty of detail on your options for externalised config:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html

The options available include placing `application.properties` / `application.yml` at the root of your classpath, so the simplest option is probably to place it in your tomcat `conf` directory.

Comment: Thanks. I am doing the same. Have placed it in tomcat's conf directory. I have referred to it using 
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties") in my Spring configuration file. But then get the following error:
java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [application.properties] cannot be opened because it does not exist. How else can I retrieve it?

Comment: It may be worth testing with `file:` and a fully qualified directory instead, in case Tomcat's conf directory isn't in your application's classpath. Beyond that, maybe make sure that `catalina.properties` loads your environment properties files. See: https://www.mulesoft.com/tcat/tomcat-classpath

Answer (score 0):

I recomend this aproximation: [Override Properties file in Spring WebApp at Runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33184807/override-properties-file-in-spring-webapp-at-runtime/33192190#33192190)

You only need something to point to your file. I use a JNDI properties.
I think it is a very bad idea to change the war between enviorements.