# Externalise properties working but not overriding existing default value in internal properties

Tags: java, spring, maven, tomcat

I have a multi module maven project, each module is a jar with its own context file and a set of default properties bundled inside the JAR.

Basically in a core module I have this :

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:core.properties</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
</bean>
```

Now i have another module that build the application by loading all relevant XML and adding its own configuration file

```
<import resource="classpath*:core-context.xml" />


<bean
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
            <value>#{systemEnvironment['foo_bar']}</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
</bean>
```

What happen is that all my configurations files are working fine except the one that has default value. I can't override them in application.properties or in the file pointed by the system variable.

I tryed to force the configuration file using the `spring.config.location`. I do see in the tomcat the message saying that I have the configuration `-Dspring.config.file=file:///...` (windows path). But spring is totally ignoring it (no message in the logs from Spring).

I tried to switch to PropertySources class without more success.

I'd very like to not have to remove all default properties and put everything in an external file, because lot of parameters are internal to the application and don't have any value for a client.

So what I am missing here ?

Comment: The property is called `spring.config.location`

Comment: @Strelok thanks, it's a typo in that post i did it right.

Comment: @Walfrat it might help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33184807/override-properties-file-in-spring-webapp-at-runtime#answer-34470235

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I finnaly found after many hours so something very ... easy.
Here is the trick : Declare the property placeholder before the import.

When you declare files in a property placeholder, it's the last that win, it seems here it's the exact opposite : the first place holder win.

```
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>classpath:application.properties</value>
            <value>#{systemEnvironment['foo_bar']}</value>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true" />
</bean>

 <import resource="classpath*:core-context.xml" />
```