# @PropertySource cannot be opened because it does not exist

Tags: java, spring

I have the problem with configuration file that is located in other directory than my jar file.

I use `@PropertySource` for loading properties.

```
@PropertySource(ignoreResourceNotFound = true, value = "${ext.properties.dir:classpath:}/properties.properties")
```

I try to run jar using following command:

```
java -jar import-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar -Dext.properties.dir=file:/C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\
```

The following error pring in logs: Properties location

> Properties location
>   [${ext.properties.dir:classpath:}/properties.properties] not resolvable:
>   class path resource [properties.properties] cannot be opened because it
>   does not exist

How can I fix this error?

Comment: this might help you - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33184807/override-properties-file-in-spring-webapp-at-runtime

Comment: @Arpit, I did same configuration as in the answer but I got `cannot be opened because it does not exist`

Comment: are you using `spring mvc` or `spring boot`?

Comment: I am using `spring boot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I saw that you are using `spring boot` application, according to the [spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) you can try to use this environment property:

```
--spring.config.location=file:/path/location/file-name.properties
```

The final instruction would be:

```
java -jar import-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar --spring.config.location=file:C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\import.properties
```

Comment: `spring.config.location` won't help him with `@PropertySource`

Comment: Did you get the same error or was it different? did you check @AbhijitSarkar's suggestion?

Comment: @JUANCALVOPINAM, thanks, `--spring.config.location` works well

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot looks for `application.properties` on classpath. You don't need an explicit `@PropertySource` annotation. And `@PropertySource` doesn't have the capability to resolve SPEL in the path, which should be evident from the error message you're getting.

Use `src/main/resources/application.properties`. When you want to use the external file, use `spring.config.location` like @juan-calvopina-m suggested in his answer.

Comment: @Alex78191 and your comment is relevant, how exactly?